# p:ajax, f:param, f:attribute support?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

How do i know whether a primefaces component supports either

1. f:ajax
2. f:facet
3. f:param
4. f:attribute

For example, how do i know wheter a f:commandButton component supports a nested f:ajax or f:param or f:attribute tag ?

Please share your ideas. Thank you !

Comment: For standard JSF components this is answered in main description of tag and API docs. However, for PrimeFaces components the tag and API docs are very sparse (there's no main description) and the User Guide PDF is not freely available, so I can't tell if it's actually in there instead.

Comment: I've read this: "We are putting tag/attribute documentation back in facelet taglib for PrimeFaces 3.0.M3 to provide docs during code/tag completion of IDEs." in Cagatay Civici's tweets, so you might be better trying PF 3.0 if you're just starting a new project

Comment: I wouldn't start a project with PF 3 since is very unstable yet...

Comment: I would go with @BalusC's answer: you'll have to look at the manual.

Comment: @BalusC: Hello, i've checked the api docs, but i couldnt seem to find the information showing which nested tags are supported. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlCommandButton.html

Comment: You should start with the tag docs: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html The API docs are only useful to learn for example what components exactly implements `UIParameter`, `UINamingContainer`, `ClientBehaviorHolder`, etc and to find out component families. Note that `<f:attribute>` is supported on every UI component. It just represents a custom attribute. It only won't be used by the standard component implementation itself.

Comment: @BalusC: I've opened the link you gave. How do i know what nested tags are supported for the commandButton ?

Comment: `<f:ajax>` tag doc http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html mentions that it's supported on components implementing `ClientBehaviorHolder` (the `UICommand` does). The `<f:attribute>` tag doc http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/attribute.html hints that it is supported on every `UIComponent` tag. The `<h:commandButton>` tag doc hints that it will decode `UIParameter` children (thus `<f:param>` is supported). There is no wording about `<f:facet>`, so it isn't supported (e.g `<h:dataTable>` tag doc does)